# How do I make an event in Delphi happen just once?

Tags: delphi, if-statement, pascal

I'm a starter programmer and I'm trying to make a text-based RPG game (Like Zork) using Delphi Pascal language.
I made an event in which the main character open a chest and find some items:

```
begin
  text1.text := 'You see a chest. It is unlocked.';
       end;
  if edit1.Text = 'Open Chest' then
  text1.Text := 'You found 50 Gold Pieces, a Short Sword, a Cloth Armor and a Satchel Bag.';
end;
```

But I want to make it in a way that, whenever someone opens the chest AFTER the first time, the chest will be empty, since the player already took the items.
In other words, when someone type 'Open Chest' in the TEdit for the second time, it says something like "It is empty."

But how?

Comment: Set a flag (a boolean) to true when it is opened for the first time.

Comment: Trying to write your game logic via `TEdit` GUI controls will lead to a mess. Time to rethink.

Comment: @David. Any suggestions on which direction he should be looking at?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you sure he is writing game logic via TEdit. Perhaps TEdit is just a component he uses for user input (he doesen't have console application). The OP didn't provide enough source to even suspect of this.

Comment: If you are indeed interested in game development perhaps you might want to join us on http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com PGD is a pascal comunity focused mainly on game development. On PGD we don't have so strict rules about asking questions so you can feely ask specific question on solving certain things or more broad questions like which approach to use. Such questions would probably be marked as off-topic here on SO.

Comment: @David: exactly my thoughts. The text returned should depend on what is in the chest, and once everything is taken from it, it is empty. That should be the logic.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use additional variable that will tell you whether chest has already been opened or not.

```
var
  ChestOpened: boolean;

// initialize at beginning
ChestOpened := false;

...

if Edit1.text = 'Open Chest' then
begin
  if ChestOpened then
    Text1.Text := 'Chest is empty'
  else
  begin
    ChestOpened := true;
    Text1.Text := 'You found 50 Gold Pieces, a Short Sword, a Cloth Armor and a Satchel Bag.'
  end;
end;
```